# The output from jupyter_datatables is not being displayed

Tags: dataframe, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, yfinance

I am a beginner in programming. I came across jupyter_datatables. But the output is not being displayed. The output I get at the end of it is [object Object].  I'm giving the code I wrote below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from jupyter_datatables import init_datatables_mode
%load_ext jupyter_require
init_datatables_mode()

stocks = pd.read_excel(r"D:\Itus\200 Day Moving Averages\Raw Data.xlsx")
stocks["Ticker Symbols"] = stocks["Ticker Symbols"]+".NS"
stocks_list = stocks["Ticker Symbols"].to_list()

stock_rets = yf.download(stocks_list, start = "2014-03-31", end = "2023-09-21")["Close"]
stock_original = stock_rets.copy()
stock_rets.fillna(method = "bfill", inplace = True)
stock_rets
```

And this is the output I got:

[image: Image of Output]

I tried updating Jupyter labs and tried the same on Jupyter Notebook. Still getting the same thing.

Comment: [object Object] is a typical output from improperly printing an object in javascript, never seen it in python. But I suspect that `yf.download` returns something that is internally javascript

Comment: Maybe there is a proper function for displaying such objects in the documentation? Or you can turn the thing into something else like a dictionary or a dataframe

Comment: Either way, this seems to come down to a question about `yfinance`, maybe add it as a tag to get attention from people who use that

Comment: Can you check if you can display a normal pandas dataframe?

Comment: Where do you define `stocks_list`?

Comment: The display without jupyter_tables is a dataframe. I'll add yfinance as a tag too.

Comment: I had defined stocks_list before yf.download. Hadn't mentioned it in the code I posted. I've put it up now.